# Folder name with space in iCloud path lead to error

Tags: icloud, path

I've a folder inside my iCloud drive which has this absolute path:

`/Users/myName/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/myFolder`

and inside `myFolder` I started a NodeJS project and I'm using `npm` to manage all packages.

The problem is that running (e.g.) `npm install -D parcel@next` leads to an error since the absolute path contains a space in the folder's name `..../Mobile Documents/.../myFolder`.

**So, since I'd like to sync my folder with iCloud, how can I bypass this?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried symlinking the path, for example to `~/myFolder`: `ln -s "~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/myFolder" ~`? You could then `cd` to `~/myFolder` and run `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. NPM script took the same absolute path. That's really annoying. Should I move the folder to the root and rsync to iCloud path to achieve this? It seems so ridiculous.